# How to write IQueryable with multiple where from same column?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert the following SQL query into a corresponding `IQueryable`:

```
select * 
from invoiceNum 
where IsActive = '1' 
  and RoleCode in ('R0090', 'R0003', 'R0084', 'R0069', 'R0006', 'R0054')  
order by UserName
```

So far I've come up with the following:

```
from u in this.Users
where (u.IsActive == true)
&& u.RoleCode == "R0003"
orderby u.UserName
```

but now I'm stuck at how to convert the remainder of the `WHERE` clause. How do I convert a SQL query that, as part of its in its `WHERE` clause, has multiple conditions that must be satisfied to an `IQueryable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Contains` for `IN`

**Note** : I'm not sure if i have your entity names correct, but i think you'll get the picture

```
var roleCodes = new List<string>{"R0090","R0003","R0084","R0069","R0006","R0054"};

var users = Users.Where(x => x.IsActive && roleCodes.Contain(x.RoleCode))
                 .OrderBy(x => x.UserName)
                 .ToList();

// or

var user = from u in Users
           where u.IsActive && roleCodes.Contains(u.RoleCode)
           orderby u.UserName
           select u;
```

---

[Enumerable.Contains Method (IEnumerable, TSource)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Determines whether a sequence contains a specified element by using
>   the default equality comparer.